# how to open content shared by other apps?

Tags: android

I want to open the links shared by apps like firefox or youtube in my webview. whenever i press the share button, [it launches my app](https://postimg.cc/image/lnoo1t1xf/), but it never loads the url-

```
// get URL from browsable intent filter
    TextView uri = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
    // get the url
    url = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    if (data == null) {
        uri.setText("");
    } else {
        uri.setText(getIntent().getData().toString());
        fadeout();
    }
    // }

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    // Load URL from Browsable intent filter if there is a valid URL pasted
    if (uri.length() > 0)
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    else
        // dont load
```

manifest

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misinterpret your question. I thought you're trying to open text link that being shared by another app. By the way, I have tried to reproduce the issue and this is my solution.

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And here is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initView();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    }
}

private void initView(){
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    //add this to enable video streaming (youtube etc.) 
    //or to handle webpage with javascript
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(null != url) {
        Log.i("URL", url);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it does not working.

Comment: In your case, just change url = getIntent().getDataString() to url = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)